# How to call an VB6.exe from foxpro 2.5 program

Tags: vb6, exe, foxpro

i have an program in foxpro 2.5 and i have an .exe file which is developed in VB6.0
my vfp program is a dos based program and we work on windows xp, we launch dos prompt in xp and the we run our vfp program. 
my problem is that when i call this program with parameters, it terminates and no result returned.
my parameter length is more than 110 character

so how could i call an .exe file in foxpro with paramter where 
the parameter is string and its length is more than 110 chars

it seems that it is memory problem anybody tell how could i manage it 
thnx

Comment: Write the call into a file and open the file from foxpro?

Comment: Do you know that the parameter length is the problem?

Comment: may be the parameter length is problem, but how could i call that program with my existing parameters

Comment: Dear sir CodingBarfield, i am not understand what you said.

Comment: Does it work if you run the command directly, outside of FoxPro?

Comment: to Deanaa - yes it works when i calls it from start -> run

Answer (score 2):

You don't say how you are calling the VB6 program from FoxPro but the RUN command should work. The following is from Visual FoxPro 7 but should apply to FoxPro 2.5.

> Executes external operating commands or programs.
>
> RUN [/N] MS-DOSCommand | ProgramName
>   -or-
>
> ! [/N] MS-DOSCommand | ProgramName Parameters MS-DOSCommand  Specifies
>   the MS-DOS command to execute. See your MS-DOS documentation for more
>   information about available MS-DOS commands.  ProgramName  Specifies
>   the program or application to run. You can specify a Windows-based or
>   an MS-DOS-based program or application.  /N  Specifies NOWAIT. Include
>   the letter N to execute another Windows-based application.  Remarks
>   You can issue RUN from within the Command window or from within a
>   program.
>
> Note   To use RUN, you must have the operating system file Command.com
>   in the current directory, or it must be located where the MS-DOS
>   COMSPEC parameter can find it. For more information on COMSPEC, see
>   your MS-DOS documentation. Caution   Do not use RUN to run disk
>   reorganization programs such as CHKDSK from within Visual FoxPro.
>   These programs modify the contents of your disk in a manner that may
>   prevent Visual FoxPro from operating properly. RUN and Visual FoxPro
>   When RUN is used to run programs outside of Visual FoxPro, it searches
>   for programs in a slightly different manner from FoxPro for MS-DOS.
>
> If the program you specify in RUN doesn't have an extension, Visual
>   FoxPro first look along the MS-DOS path for a Program Information File
>   (PIF) with the name you specify. A PIF lets you run a non-Windows
>   program under Windows. You can specify parameters for the program,
>   whether the program is run in a window or on the full screen, the
>   amount of memory allocated for the program, and so on.
>
> If the PIF is found, the program specified in the PIF is executed with
>   the PIF parameters. If a PIF isn't found, the MS-DOS path is then
>   searched for an executable file with the name you specify.
>
> When a PIF isn't found, Visual FoxPro uses FOXRUN.PIF, a PIF installed
>   in the Visual FoxPro directory. FOXRUN.PIF is configured to run the
>   program in a window. You can modify FOXRUN.PIF to run programs in
>   another configuration.
>
> Windows 2000 logo Certification   If you plan to submit your
>   application for certification, you should not use the RUN command,
>   because it can potentially violate the following System Group Policy
>   requirement.
>
> "RUN only allowed Windows application - your application must not
>   start any application that is not on this list. Note this does not
>   apply when launching applications through COM. If you use
>   ShellExecuteEx, Windows 2000 will perform this check automatically."
>   Instead, you should use DECLARE DLL with ShellExecuteEx.API.
>
> FOXRUN.PIF   Foxrun.pif allows you to execute MS-DOS® and Windows®
>   programs and commands from within Visual FoxPro. Foxrun.pif must be in
>   the same directory as Vfp7.exe in Visual FoxPro.
>
> /N means NOWAIT. Include the letter N to execute another Windows-based
>   application. For example, the following statement opens the Windows
>   Character Map accessory:
>
> ! /N CHARMAP.EXE  The following example opens the Windows color picker
>   from the Windows Control Panel:
>
> ! /N CONTROL COLOR A Windows-based application executed with RUN /N or
>   ! /N behaves the same way the application does when you open it
>   through the Windows Explorer or by selecting Run from the Start menu.
>   You can switch between the application and Visual FoxPro or FoxPro for
>   Windows using the standard Windows operations.
>
> You can include an optional numeric value immediately after /N to
>   specify how the Windows-based application is opened. Do not include
>   any spaces between /N and the numeric value. The following table lists
>   the numeric value you can include and describes the state of the
>   Windows-based application when opened.
>
> Value Application attributes  1 Active and normal size  2 Active and
>   minimized  3 Active and maximized  4 Inactive and normal size  7
>   Inactive and minimized
>
> Running MS-DOS Programs in Visual FoxPro   By default, Foxrun.pif runs
>   the specified external MS-DOS program in a window. While the MS-DOS
>   program or command is running, the title of the window is FoxPro Run
>   Command. In Visual FoxPro, the FoxPro Run Command window is closed
>   after the external program or command is finished executing.
>
> You can use the Windows PIF editor to customize Foxrun.pif. You can
>   edit the PIF to specify if the Inactive FoxPro Run Command window is
>   left open or is closed (the default in Visual FoxPro) with the Close
>   Window on Exit check box. You can also open external programs in a
>   full screen by selecting Full Screen; allocate memory for the program;
>   and so on.
>
> Memory Considerations   By default, Foxrun.pif allocates a minimum of
>   256K of memory for running an external command or program. If you do
>   not have 256K of free conventional memory, Visual FoxPro displays an
>   error message. To correct this, try one or both of the following:
>
> Close applications and files to free up additional memory.  Edit
>   Foxrun.pif to reduce the amount of memory required in the KB Required
>   text box.  If the external command requires more than 256K, MS-DOS
>   displays an error message in the FoxPro Run Command window. To correct
>   this, edit your Foxrun.pif to increase the amount of memory required
>   in the KB Required text box.

Comment: Thank you very much MR.Dave
this article will really help me

Comment: it seems that it is problem of short memory

tell me how to increase memrory to run an external exe program
we are working on Windows XP. and our foxpro program is dos based
we lanch ms dos in windows xp then we start our vfp program and in vfp the external exe calls